# Counting the characters in a .txt file

Tags: c#, file-io

I need to count the characters in a .txt file. I have pulled the file and now I need to count the characters. Here is what I have so far.

```
namespace CharCount
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = @"dataentry.txt";
            string result;
            result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("GetFileName {0} returns {1}", fileName, result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting number of characters in a file C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214772/counting-number-of-characters-in-a-file-c-sharp)

Comment: -1: Your sample is absolutely unrelated to reading from file.

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The answers offered are both useful, but nobody specified the difference very clearly...

`File.ReadAllText(filename).Length`

Downside: You have to read the whole file, performance may matter here.

Upside: .NET will consider character encoding when reading the file. If you have a non-ascii file and some characters are actually multiple bytes this will give you the number of characters and not the number of bytes.

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
long fileLength = f.Length;
```

Downside: This doesn't actually check the contents of the file and can't know whether the text in it is one-byte-per-character or not. It'll return the number of bytes, which may be different to the number of characters.

Upside: Performance - you don't actually have to read the file.

So bascially use the second if you are in a position to make safe assumptions about the input file (Comment it accordingly for your assumtption) and use the first if you can't be sure what type of text file you're recieving.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
long fileLength = f.Length; **** However, if anyone s going to do this make sure there are no spaces at the end of the text file because for some reason the spaces are counted.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
File.ReadAllText(filename).Length
```

> According to MSDN the Length property of string 'Gets the number of
>   characters in the current String object.'

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx

The other answers you find use streams which returns number of bytes.

> Gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(fileName);
long fileLength = f.Length;
//fileLength should be the number of characters
```

or

```
public int GetNumOfCharsInFile(string filePath)
{
    int count = 0;
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        while (sr.Read() != -1)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

See: [Counting number of characters in a file C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214772/counting-number-of-characters-in-a-file-c-sharp)

Comment: -1: Copy-paste of code from duplicate question is not really answer - propose as duplicate, add as comment or if really want to answer - add better explanation that original.